# Using importxml with key in Google Spreadsheets to fetch from Directions API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-sheets, directions

I am using Google Spreadsheets to populate a table of times between different points on a map, and am using importxml to do so.

It works fine as a test, however I cannot figure out how to also append a key that I got for the Maps API. Where do I insert it in the code line? Or am I missing something? Can't find any usage samples on the net.

The code itself looks like this for a random cell (L9 in this case):

```
=if(J10="","",if(J9="","",importxml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" & if(J9=1,vlookup($B$1,database!$A$1:$D,4,FALSE),vlookup(J9,database!$E$1:$H,4,FALSE)) & "&destination=" & vlookup(J10,database!$E$1:$H,4,FALSE) & "&sensor=false&alternatives=false","//leg/duration/value"))/1440/60)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (if you replace "MY_KEY" with your actual key):

```
 =if(J10="","",if(J9="","",importxml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" & if(J9=1,vlookup($B$1,database!$A$1:$D,4,FALSE),vlookup(J9,database!$E$1:$H,4,FALSE)) & "&destination=" & vlookup(J10,database!$E$1:$H,4,FALSE) & "&sensor=false&alternatives=false&key=MY_KEY","//leg/duration/value"))/1440/60)
```

If you put your key in a cell in the spreadsheet, you could also include that in the URL (append it to the URL like you are doing with "&origin=" and "&destination=").

Comment: Ty, but I tried this one before, and for some reason it only returns an "ERROR: Imported content is empty" in the cell.

I can't figure out what's wrong - either I can't use the key like that, or not at all with this function, or... No idea.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching through multiple resources, but ended up finding the answer by fumbling with the XML-document from the API itself. The answer is that Google has restructured the XML-file and that `"//leg/duration/value"` is used to tell Google which part of the XML-file we need to load. This string should be updated to `"DirectionsResponse/route/leg/step/duration/value"` in order to fit the current API.

Furthermore the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) seems a bit more solid, so for my project, it made more sense to use the following:

```
=importxml("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?&origins="&E2&"&destinations="&F2&"&sensor=false&alternatives=false&key=[YOUR-KEY]","/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/value")/1000)
```

Note that the XML-structure is a bit different as well:

```
"/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/value"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
=importXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&origins="&AA$3&"&destinations="&$Y23&"&key=[my-api-key]","//distance/text")
```

It works perfectly and returns value [657 mi], but I am only able to make 100 calls at a time before it gets stuck in loading.